# Is there something like TimeSpan in android development?

Tags: android

I need to know if there is something like a timespan in android development?

in C# there is something like and I like to use it in two ways:

1. generate a timespan and then add e.g. minutes and then display the whole span
2. generate the timespan between two DateTime (what is the equivalent for DateTime in android?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public long addSeconds(long dt,int sec) //method to add seconds in time  
{

    Date Dt = new Date(dt);
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setCalendar(cal);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(Dt.getTime());
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, sec);
    return cal.getTime().getTime();

}
```

pass date and time in sec, it will return modified time...

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there's no `TimeSpan` like class yet natively available in Java, but you can achieve this with few lines of code.

```
Calendar startDate = getStartDate();
Calendar endDate = getEndDate();

long totalMillis = endDate.getTimeInMillis() - startDate.getTimeInMillis();
int seconds = (int) (totalMillis / 1000) % 60;
int minutes =  ((int)(totalMillis / 1000) / 60) % 60;
int hours = (int)(totalMillis / 1000) / 3600;
```

Answer (score 3):

Android has DateUtils, the method "formatElapsedTime" does what you need if you give it the right input.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the "TimeSpan" in milliseconds. To convert milliseconds to a formatted one, you can do a little fast and elegant calculation in your function like this,

```
public static String GetFormattedTimeSpan(final long ms) {
    long x = ms / 1000;
    long seconds = x % 60;
    x /= 60;
    long minutes = x % 60;
    x /= 60;
    long hours = x % 24;
    x /= 24;
    long days = x;

    return String.format("%d days %d hours %d minutes %d seconds", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Calendar class.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-calendar.html

Answer (score 0):

Dates in Java are awkward. Have a look at https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android