# How to use Lap Button using timer program in android(lap button code for timmer application in android)

Tags: android, timer

I have one button start and three editText. If I press the start button then timer starts and the button text changes to Lap and hour minutes and seconds are displayed in edittext1. If I press Lap button then editText1's values are stop. All three values of editText1 are displayed in editText2 at stop position of editText1.

Please help me for Lap button source code. I have the following code so far:

```
package com.example.timmerproject;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LapActivity extends Activity
{
    EditText ed1,ed2,ed3;
    Button btntimer;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    long startTime=0;
    Handler h2 = new Handler();

    Runnable run = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            int seconds = (int)(millis/1000);
            int hours =seconds/3600;
            int minutes = (seconds % 3600)/60;

            seconds = seconds % 60;
            ed1.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours,minutes,seconds));
            h2.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };

    class firstTask extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };

    class secondTask extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LapActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                    int seconds = (int)(millis/1000);
                    int hours =seconds/3600;
                    int minutes = (seconds % 3600)/60;

                    seconds = seconds % 60;
                    ed2.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours,minutes,seconds));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    class thirdTask extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LapActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                    int seconds = (int)(millis/1000);
                    int hours =seconds/3600;
                    int minutes = (seconds % 3600)/60;

                    seconds = seconds % 60;
                    ed3.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours,minutes,seconds));
                }
            });
        }           
    }

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lap);
        ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed11);
        ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed12);
        ed3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed13);
        btntimer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.lapbutton);

        btntimer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Button btn = (Button)v;

                if(btn.getText().equals("Stop"))
                {
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer.purge();
                    h2.removeCallbacks(run);
                    btn.setText("Start");
                }
                else
                {
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(new firstTask(), 0,500);
                    timer.schedule(new secondTask(),  0,500);
                    timer.schedule(new thirdTask(),  0,500);
                    h2.postDelayed(run, 0);
                    btn.setText("Stop");       
                }   
            }   
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136508/is-there-someting-like-timespan-in-android-development

Comment: no,i want to source code for Lap button.When i press Lap button then edittext1's value(hours,minute,seconds) wiil be displayed in editText2 and editText1's value will be stop.

Comment: no one can have this answer????

Comment: It looks like you're almost there. Try adding a new long lastLap = 0; and when you get millis, use currentTimeMillis() - startTime - lastLap, then set lastLap = currentTimeMillis()?

Comment: please give me a code for that.

Comment: Mr. Rubber Mallet, i try your code for that program but doesn't work it. Please give me a sample prog. Thanx for help.

Comment: This looks like java code. If it is then add a tag for it so that you will be able to find help faster.