# Get the number of days between two days

Tags: android, date

Can anyone point me to some code which can give me the number of days between two days.The two days are going to be the current day and a particular day entered by the user.Thanks

Comment: We can.. but did you searched ever for this solution? Search `get days between two dates, java` into Google. :)

Comment: Actually pankaj i am getting the days as string in another activity through an intent.Now i want to subtract the two dates.So there lies the problem.But now i have the solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136508/is-there-someting-like-timespan-in-android-development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for date difference manipulation.

```
     String fd=from_date;//date get from mysql database as string.
     String td=to_date;//Today's date as string.
   if(!fd.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !td.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
       SimpleDateFormat formatter;
       Date frmdt=new Date(fd);
       formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
       String s1 = formatter.format(frmdt);
       Date todt=new Date(td);
       String s2 = formatter.format(todt);
       Date frmdate = sdf.parse(s1);
       Date todate = sdf.parse(s2);
              if(frmdate.compareTo(todate)<=0) {
                            //do your stuff
                 } else {
                            // do your stuff
                 }
         }
```

Here I give today's date as string.you can give as you like as current date format.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
long diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
long seconds = diff / 1000;
long minutes = seconds / 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
long days = hours / 24;
```

You can also check this [link](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-calculate-difference-in-days-between-two-dates/).

Hope this helps...